# Reg of Vec of Valid(Vec

Tags: scala, riscv, chisel

I am continually getting an error due to the use of different sized Vecs. Is there a way I could implement this so that `b`, `c`, and `d` would all take just their respective # of Vec elements from `a`.

```
val a = Reg(Vec(10, Valid(Vec(32, UInt(8.W)))))
val b = Reg(Vec(10, Valid(Vec(16, UInt(8.W)))))
val c = Reg(Vec(8, Valid(Vec(24, UInt(8.W)))))
val d = Reg(Vec(7, Valid(Vec(32, UInt(8.W)))))

for (i <- 0 to 10) {
  b(i).bits := a(i).bits
}
for (i <- 0 to 8) {
  c(i).bits := a(i).bits
}
for (i <- 0 to 7) {
  d(i).bits := a(i).bits
}
```

Here is the error message I am receiving.

```
Connection between sink (UInt<8>[16](Reg in file)) and source (UInt<8>[32](Reg in file)) failed @: Sink and Source are different length Vecs.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `slice` method to take a portion of any Scala `Seq` (Chisel's `Vec` extends `Seq`):

```scala
val a = Reg(Vec(10, Valid(Vec(32, UInt(8.W)))))
val b = Reg(Vec(10, Valid(Vec(16, UInt(8.W)))))

for (i <- 0 until 10) {
  b(i).bits := a(i).bits.slice(0, 16)
}
```

This all is very index heavy though, relying on knowing the sizes of your Vecs, we could use the `Seq` method `zip` which allows you to iterate on corresponding elements in two `Seqs`. If one is longer than the other, it just truncates to the shorter one. The below is functionally identical to the `for` loop with the `slice`:

```scala
for ((bb, aa) <- b zip a) { // I'm using infix notation: b zip a == b.zip(a)
  for ((x, y) <- bb.bits zip aa.bits) {
    x := y
  }
}
```

Note the lack of any indices, this just works no matter the size, so we could use this in a reusable function:

```scala
def nestedConnect(x: Vec[Valid[Vec[UInt]]], y: Vec[Valid[Vec[UInt]]]): Unit = {
  for ((xx, yy) <- x zip y) {
    for ((l, r) <- xx.bits zip yy.bits) {
      l := r
    }
  }
}
```

We can then do all of your connects by using this function:

```scala
nestedConnect(b, a)
nestedConnect(c, a)
nestedConnect(d, a)
```

Executable example showing that this works: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/SFh1PratTCWhxHc55VGeHg

Comment: Now how would this work if I wanted to do the inverse? For example I wanted to send `b(i).bits` to `a(i).bits` where half of `a(i)`'s Vec's would be would be empty.

Comment: Same thing, just flip the arguments to `nestedConnect`. Because `zip` truncates to the shorter `Seq`, it will only connect to the low indices of the larger `Vec`.